# Get-Item path not working as expected

Tags: powershell-extensions

Can anyone explain what's going on here with this Sitecore Power Shell script?

We have 2 websites set up on 1 `Sitecore` instance, they're as follows:

```
/sitecore/content/siteA

/sitecore/content/siteB
```

The below query returns all items under /sitecore/content/siteA/

```
$contentsToUpdate = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content/siteA//*"
```

The below query returns all items under /sitecore/content/siteB/

```
$contentsToUpdate = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content/siteB//*"
```

The line below seems to return all items under /sitecore/content/siteA/ but nothing from siteB.

```
$contentsToUpdate = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content//*"
```

I was hoping and expecting that the third example would give me pages under both /siteA/ and /siteB/ but it doesn't seem to be doing that despite all 3 of the commands appearing to access sub-directories fine.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: How many items are return from first query? and from second? maybe there are more than max configured in Sitecore? https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/03/querymaxitems-in-sitecore-81.html

Comment: Could you please check Query.MaxItems setting value. you can check it in showconfig.aspx by running sitecoreinstance/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in some of the comments, the `-Query` option is influenced by the maximum items setting in Sitecore. With this parameter set for the command you are essentially running a Sitecore Query.

If you are trying to return items from each site you can use a different parameter set which is not bound by the `MaxItems` setting.

**Example:** The following walks the tree by looping through the children of each item.

```
$contentsToUpdate = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content" -Recurse
```

Comment: thanks all! Seems to be the MaxItems issue as it's returning 300 which matches the default setting... I'll try with the -Path option and see what gets returned!